Assigned function from library in Object Typescript
I'm trying to assign a field inside my interface to a function from an external library like so:
import {
  Accelerometer,
} from 'expo-sensors';

type SensorInterface = {
  permChecker: () => Promise<PermissionResponse>;
};

type MonitorService = {
  accelerometer: SensorInterface;
};

export const monitorService: MonitorService = {
  accelerometer: {
    permChecker: Accelerometer.requestPermissionsAsync,
  },
};


when I use the global variable monitorService, permStatus is undefined. I'm using it like so:
const sensors = ['accelerometer'];
for (const sensor of sensors) {
      const service: SensorInterface = monitorService[sensor as keyof MonitorService];
      console.log(`service = ${JSON.stringify(service)}`);
      const perm = await service.permChecker();
    }

Thanks a lot for your help !
I'm expecting the function to be defined and callable.

What is the output of the stringify?

an empty object:
service = {}

what's the console log of monitorService?

same thing:
monitor service = {"accelerometer":{}}

My stupid workaround was to create a class inside a function instead of an object on the global scope.
